# Visual Studio Code Snippets do not work with K&R style braces

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I am running the latest version of Visual Studio 2019. I have changed my C++ code to use K&R style braces by going to **Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** > **C/C++** > **Code Style** > **Formatting** > **New Lines** and changing all the options to `Keep on same line, but add a space before`. The issue is that when I do this code snippets no longer work correctly, for example:

Normally when using Allman style braces the `if` code snippet would look like this:

```
if (true)
{

}
```

What I expected it to look like when using K&R style braces was this:

```
if (true) {

}
```

But what it actually looked like was this:

```
if (true)   {

}
```

This is very annoying as whenever I use a code snippet to complete an `if` statement, `for` loop or anything else I have to waste time removing the extra characters it inserts. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It is Visual Studios subtle hint that Allman is the only correct indentation style ;)

Comment: I never knew my IDE had such a strong opinion of my coding style :p

Comment: I doubt there's any satisfactory answer you could get here.

Comment: Where do you suggest I look then?

Comment: Can't reproduce. What are doing exactly?

Comment: This was happening for a while in my VS IDE. Then it stopped happening. But I have no idea what I did or didn't do to either make it start or make it stop. Maybe an update?

Comment: @ShadowHolder Perhaps here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home

Comment: @rustyx Exactly what I said in my post, I switched to using K&R style braces and then used the tab key to autocomplete a code snippet and it placed multiple spaces after the close bracket instead of just one.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks if nobody posts an answer here in the next few hours I'll look there.

Comment: @AdrianMole For me it seemed to be an update that made it start happening. I am running the latest version. I also tried resetting to default settings...

Comment: There have been quite a few VS updates in the past week. I think this issue was between one or two of those.

Comment: @AdrianMole I suppose I could try and find an older version somewhere on the internet but that isn't really an acceptable long term fix :/

Comment: If I set "Position on same line..." for functions and press Ctrl-K-D, then it formats functions with exactly one space between `) {`. VS 16.9.4. BTW VS 2019 supports clang-format, which is nice and cross-platform. Might want to try it instead (see Formatting--General--Enable ClangFormat). It'll then use formatting settings from .clang-format

Comment: @ShadowHolder, Here is the same thread, I suggest you could follow the thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/360533/visual-studio-code-snippets-don39t-work-with-kampr.html

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I have replied to that thread, thank you for your help.